# Django: how to build relations and queries the best way?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm new to Django, and I'm having difficulties with related objects.  What is so easy in terms of SQL seems to be quite tricky here.

I have a simple DB that looks like this:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey, GenericRelation
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.db import models

class Language(models.Model):
  code = models.CharField(max_length = 2)
  name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)

class Translation(models.Model):
  content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
  object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
  content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

  language = models.ForeignKey(Language)
  title = models.TextField()
  text = models.TextField()

class Article(models.Model):
  pub_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name = "Publication date")
  visible = models.BooleanField(default = False)
  translations = GenericRelation(Translation)
```

This is essentially a follow-up to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26365499/1380150).  Thanks to [Andrea Corbellini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1913824/andrea-corbellini), the above model looks very clear and simple.

Now I want to show the articles on the web page.  There is a current language, and I need to select only articles that 1) are visible and 2) have a translation to the current language.  In SQL this would mean joining several tables and filtering them in a single query.

How to do that in Django?  This question actually includes two questions: how to make a fast query and how to pass the result to the template.

What I do now is first filtering by *visible* and ordering by *pub_date*, then iterating through the query set, picking the articles which have a proper translation, and finally copying their fields into the context because the template engine doesn't seem to understand how to access the related objects.  Here is the code; it looks very awkward:

```
  articles = Article.objects.filter(visible = True).order_by('-pub_date')
  recent_news = []
  for article in articles:
    content = article.content(translation.get_language())
    if not content.exists():
      continue
    content = content[0]
    recent_news.append({
      'pub_date': article.pub_date,
      'title': content.title,
      'abstract': content.text,
      'text': content.text
    })
  context = { 'recent_news_list': recent_news }
```

What would help here is something like a 'meta model' or some middleware that would do some of this job and cache the result so requesting articles for some language would require a single query.  But is that a good way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all the information you need to send to the template is in the Translation model, I would do the query on that model, and send that to the template. The only thing you need that is in the Article model is the `visible` field, so you can filter on that:

```
article = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Article)
article_ids = Article.objects.filter(visible=True).values_list('id')
translations = Translation.objects.filter(content_type=article, object_id__in=article_ids)
context = {'recent_news_list: translations}
```

This is just three queries: one to get the ContentType (although this will probably be cached automatically), one to get the translations, and one to get the articles (and Django may indeed do the third as a subquery of the second).

It's always going to be slightly complicated though; that's the price you pay for using generic relations. I know your other question does have multiple types related to Translation, but if you can get away without doing that things would indeed be much simpler.

Comment: This is interesting, thanks for the explanation.  However, I cannot go without fields of the Article model—I understand that I hadn't written about that so I've fixed my question now.  For instance, I use pub_date for ordering, and I need to display it in the template.  That's why I was writing about database joins.

Comment: OK, fair enough. I'd still recommend going through Translation though - you can go from translation to article directly in the template just by doing `translation.content_object`. You might want to use a technique I wrote about [on my blog](http://blog.roseman.org.uk/2010/02/22/django-patterns-part-4-forwards-generic-relations/) to reduce the number of db lookups.